# Object database for .NET

Tags: .net, object-oriented-database

Are there any object databases for .NET or with bindings for .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems) some.

You could also consider using [Bamboo.Prevalence](http://bbooprevalence.sourceforge.net/) - a .NET persistence engine similar to [Prevayler](http://www.prevayler.org/wiki/) for Java. That is not a database in a usual sense (more on this [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-objprev/index.html)), but could be appropriate in some cases.

Comment: I selected this as the accepted answer because of the linked Wikipedia list. All answers are correct but only one can be the accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

[db4o](http://www.db4o.com/about/) works on both Java and .NET.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at 100% .NET object database - siaqodb ( http://siaqodb.com )

Answer (score 4):

Majority of object databases are not really .NET databases, as they are written in Java, and then converted into .NET (C#) by some kind of converter. That results in really poor performing code.

You can look into [Eloquera Database](http://www.eloquera.com), which is pure .NET-based object database with SQL, and performing from 10 to 1000 times faster than db4o.

Answer (score 3):

[STSdb](http://stsdb.com/content.php?r=186-Fully-embedded-NET-database) is coded in 100% pure managed C#. This allows its use under different .NET platforms like .NET Framework and Mono. db4o works on both Java and .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Intersystems Caché also has a managed .NET provider - can't speak from experience about its quality and usability, though:

http://www.intersystems.com/cache/technology/components/net/index.html

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Databases for .NET are also listed in [SharpToolbox.com's DBMS category](http://sharptoolbox.com/categories/dbms).
You'll find object databases in there.